# SwiftUI: Function declares an opaque return type, but the return statements in its body do not have matching underlying types

Tags: swift, swiftui

I was trying to write a static function like this:

```
enum NavigationViewKind {
    case test1(String)
    case test2
}

struct NavigationViewManager {
    static func make<V: View>(_ kind: NavigationViewKind, _ contentView: @escaping () -> V) -> some View {
        switch kind {
        case .test1(let text):
            return NavigationView {
                contentView()
                    .navigationBarTitle(text, displayMode: .inline)
            }
        case .test2:
            return NavigationView {
                contentView()
                    .navigationBarTitle("Initial", displayMode: .large)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm getting this error :

> Function declares an opaque return type, but the return statements in its body do not have matching underlying types

Can you please help me understanding and solving this error?

Thank you

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You need to use `@ViewBuilder` in this case (and remove returns, because return disables ViewBuilder)

```
struct NavigationViewManager {
    @ViewBuilder
    static func make<V: View>(_ kind: NavigationViewKind, _ contentView: @escaping () -> V) -> some View {
        switch kind {
        case .test1(let text):
            NavigationView {
                contentView()
                    .navigationBarTitle(text, displayMode: .inline)
            }
        case .test2:
            NavigationView {
                contentView()
                    .navigationBarTitle("Initial", displayMode: .large)
            }
        }
    }
}
```